# How to get Visual Studio Code to visually display the program as you write it

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

In this [guy's youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jOqYe0eFqY) he has a setup where the right half of his screen displays the "coffee cup" as he builds it with CSS code on the left half of the screen.

After searching all around I cannot find a method to get Visual Studio Code to render an image of the code as it is being written. It seems I have to click the "debug and run" button manually to get it to compile each time. This makes it difficult to see the effect of a small change in CSS on the design output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks team!

Comment: Hi, to do this, you just need to download the Live Server extension in the VSCode marketplace, after a few seconds it'll pop up on the bottom of your VSCode. (The Market Place is the second to last icon on the right side of your VSCode).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One follow up question sir, I have the Live Server enabled but it opens the program in my separate browser window and does not open in the split screen to the right of the code. How are you able to get the browser embedded in the VSC split-screen so I have code on the left and browser on the right? I've tried a few things, but cant seem to get this to work! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Its not letting me accept your answer for some reason. The green checkmark toggle is not there :(